# No connectivity with Composer v2

Tags: php, composer-php

After upgrading to composer v2 all requests time out.

With Composer v1 everything worked perfectly, the only thing that changes is the upgrade to v2. I'm on a Mac running PHP 7.4.11, installed through Homebrew.

Check the `composer diagnose -vvv` output below. The first one runs on composer 2.0.3, then I do a rollback (composer `self-update --1` also times out) and then a diagnose with good connectivity on 1.10.16.

```
❯ composer diagnose -vvv
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem: valid
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): hg branch
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil branch list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil tag list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): svn info --xml
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 2.0.3 (2020-10-28 15:50:55) with PHP 7.4.11 on Darwin / 19.6.0
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): hg branch
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil branch list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil tag list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): svn info --xml
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: Executing command (CWD): git config color.ui
OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10005 milliseconds
Checking https connectivity to packagist: Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10006 milliseconds
Checking github.com rate limit: Downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit
FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10005 milliseconds
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions
FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10005 milliseconds
Composer version: 2.0.3
PHP version: 7.4.11
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
cURL version: 7.73.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1h
zip extension: OK
~ took 44s 
❯ composer self-update -r 
Rolling back to version 2020-10-24_09-55-59-1.10.16.
~ took 4s 
❯ composer diagnose -vvv 
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem: valid
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): hg branch
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil branch list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil tag list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): svn info --xml
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.10.16 (2020-10-24 09:55:59) with PHP 7.4.11 on Darwin / 19.6.0
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Loading auth config from COMPOSER_AUTH
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/auth.json
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): hg branch
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil branch list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): fossil tag list
Executing command (/Users/mymac/.composer): svn info --xml
Reading /Users/mymac/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: Executing command (CWD): git config color.ui
OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
OK
Checking github.com rate limit: Downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit
OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions
You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.10.16 => 2.0.3)
Composer version: 1.10.16
PHP version: 7.4.11
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

What I've tried already unsuccessfully: system restart, complete reinstall of PHP, fresh install of composer, removing global config and auth files. All with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be connected to a faulty DNS entry. My first entry pointed to a no longer used raspberry pi running pi-hole. It seems that composer did not skip to the next entry but instead just timed out.

---

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9376) which describes the same problem and solution.

The author of Composer mentions that Composer-2 uses Curl now, instead of PHP streams, for connecting.
This provoke a change in network handling and introduces the timeout issue, in case the local network DNS is not optimally configured.

A solution is to skip the faulty auto-configured DNS and set one manually, to ensure that a non-faulty one is used instead as first choice.
You can try setting `1.1.1.1` (Cloudflare's server) as primary DNS in your OS network configuration.

However, the automatic DNS has a problem, so report in any case the problem to your system administrator.